# how to join two bytes32 values in solidity?

Tags: solidity, assembly

Below is work example of joining two bytes arrays. I wonder how I can join two bytes32 using assembly or solidity? two bytes32 values should serve as an input and a joined bytes32 is an output.

```
function mergeBytes(bytes memory a, bytes memory b) public pure returns (bytes memory c) {
    // Store the length of the first array
    uint alen = a.length;
    // Store the length of BOTH arrays
    uint totallen = alen + b.length;
    // Count the loops required for array a (sets of 32 bytes)
    uint loopsa = (a.length + 31) / 32;
    // Count the loops required for array b (sets of 32 bytes)
    uint loopsb = (b.length + 31) / 32;
    assembly {
        let m := mload(0x40)
        // Load the length of both arrays to the head of the new bytes array
        mstore(m, totallen)
        // Add the contents of a to the array
        for {  let i := 0 } lt(i, loopsa) { i := add(1, i) } { mstore(add(m, mul(32, add(1, i))), mload(add(a, mul(32, add(1, i))))) }
        // Add the contents of b to the array
        for {  let i := 0 } lt(i, loopsb) { i := add(1, i) } { mstore(add(m, add(mul(32, add(1, i)), alen)), mload(add(b, mul(32, add(1, i))))) }
        mstore(0x40, add(m, add(32, totallen)))
        c := m
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to merge two arrays ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot concatenate two `bytes32` into one `bytes32`, because there is not enough space.

If you just want a way to combine two `bytes32` into one without preserving the original data, you can use XOR:

```
bytes32 c = a ^ b;
```

... or you can use a hashing function:

```
bytes32 c = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(a, b));
```

If you want to concatenate two `bytes32` into one `bytes`, you can do something like this:

```
function concat(bytes32 b1, bytes32 b2) pure external returns (bytes memory)
{
    bytes memory result = new bytes(64);
    assembly {
        mstore(add(result, 32), b1)
        mstore(add(result, 64), b2)
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As stated by Jesse you cannot join two bytes32 and obtain a bytes32 but you should be able to concatenate both to obtain a bytes array.

One option is to use [`abi.encodePacked`](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.1/units-and-global-variables.html#abi-encoding-and-decoding-functions) for such endeavor

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.6.0;

contract Ballot {
    function concatenate(bytes32 x, bytes32 y) public pure returns (bytes memory) {
        return abi.encodePacked(x, y);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As of Solidity v0.8.12 the `string.concat` and `bytes.concat` methods are available

So this problem can be easily solved with

```
bytes32 memory b1;
bytes32 memory b2;
bytes.concat(b1, b2);
```

Source: [Solidity docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.12/types.html#the-functions-bytes-concat-and-string-concat)